# how to retrieve number of rows inserted through Snowflake javascript API?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I run an INSERT/SELECT in Snowflake through the javascript API, it looks like the rowCount returned is 1 regardless of how many rows were inserted...

```
myStatement = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: mySql} );
myStatement.execute();

rowCount = myStatement.getRowCount();
```

Is there a SIMPLE way to retrieve the number of rows inserted?
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you are not doing something wrong. There is a difference in Snowflake from executing a query like an `SELECT * ....`  from executing an `UPDATE\DELETE\INSERT`  statement.

In snowflake if you perform a select, and what to know the number of returned rows then you are correct you execute:

```
myStatement = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: "SELECT * FROM TABLE1"} );
myStatement.execute();
rowCount = myStatement.getRowCount();
```

When you execute a 'INSERT\UPDATE\DELETE` snowflake returns just one row that as indicated on answer by @greg-pavlik has the number of modified rows.
However there is even a more simple way.

```
myStatement = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: "INSERT ..."} );
myStatement.execute();
rowCount = myStatement.getNumRowsAffected();
```

Comment: This is VERY interesting. Thanks.
How did you find this out? I can't see it in the documentation...

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#object-statement

Answer (score 2):

When you insert rows outside of a stored procedure, you will get a single row in return that tells you the number of rows inserted. The same will happen in a stored procedure, so you need to grab the result set and read the number in the first row, first column of that result set.

```
create or replace temp table foo(v string);

-- This returns "number of rows", 2
insert into foo(v) values ('1'), ('2');

create or replace procedure foo()
returns string
language javascript
as
$$

    var mySql = "insert into foo(v) values ('1'), ('2');";
    var myStatement = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: mySql} );
    var rs = myStatement.execute();
    rs.next()
    return "Inserted " + rs.getColumnValue(1) + " rows.";
    
$$;

call foo();
```